# My fiancee is already married

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-comes-alive

I decided to gift my fiancee (to which I gifted an engagement ring to) a wedding ring but she says she's already married. I've tried divorcing using the cleric, but it said that I wasn't married.